# Rails deployment using Phusion Passenger on Bluehost

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger, bluehost

I am trying to deploy a rails application on Bluehost using passenger and I have been failing all the time.
I installed the passenger gem using:

```
gem install passenger
```

And also ran:

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

And ran all my db migrations and also did a asset precompile

The problem is, I am trying to host it on a sub-domain, so I did the following steps:

1. Created a sub-domain.
2. Created a sym link from rails app pointing to the sub-domain.
3. Added the following lines to my .htaccess:

> PassengerEnabled On
>
> PassengerAppRoot /home/username/rails_apps/my_app

And when I navigate to my domain in the browser it gives me:

> Internal Server Error.
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@sub.domain.com

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you don't need to install `passenger`. Have you read their documentation? https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/rails

Comment: I have installed passenger. And I have also tried their documentation, but did not work for me.

Comment: what do the apache error and access logs say?

Comment: They don't say anything. I viewed my error logs from the cpanel provided by bluehost. Is there any other way of seeing my apache error logs?

Comment: I am also facing the same error. I also installed passenger. Now its giving me "database configuration does not specify adapter" but when I start server using rails s it works.. kinda weird error..

Answer (score 1):

Hey have you checked user & group in your httpd conf file?
make sure that if you have user/group www-data in httpd conf then your project directories should have same owner & group.

Comment: I am planning to buy a VPS from linode very soon.
I am not quite happy with a shared server, as it does not offer much.
Thanks for the reply.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

I also tried doing the same thing, but was unsuccessful, but when I dig a bit deep I figured out following:

- The apache server in Bluehost uses passenger in different path. Hence our installation would not affect it.
- Passenger3.x of Bluehost is using ruby 1.8 as default one, hence the ruby version cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

[Check Bluehost](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/rails) on what needs to be in the .htaccess file.
Mine looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
Options -MultiViews
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
#Set this to whatever environment you'll be running in
RailsEnv production
RackBaseURI /home/rails_apps/my_app
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home/<my_bluehost_username>/ruby/gems
</IfModule>
```

You should use this command to find your ruby gems location:

```
gem env
```